# My menu showing up at the top left of the screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I built a menu bar using the menu control in WPF and it had been working but at some point the menu started showing up on the top left of my first monitor regardless of where in the screen I had the window.  Even if I move the main window to the second monitor the menu still shows up in the first monitor.

[image: Menu Image]

Here is the code for the menu control:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <MenuItem Header="_New" Command="New" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Open" Command="Open" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Close" Command="Close" InputGestureText="Ctrl+W" />
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Save" Command="Save" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S" />
        <MenuItem Header="Save _As" Command="SaveAs" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Shift+S" />
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Command="{StaticResource CommandBinding_Exit}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Q" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
        <MenuItem Header="_Add" Command="{StaticResource CommandBinding_Add}" InputGestureText="" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Command="{StaticResource CommandBinding_Edit}" InputGestureText="" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Delete" Command="Delete" InputGestureText="" />
        <Separator/>
        <MenuItem Header="Cut" Command="Cut" InputGestureText="Ctrl+X" />
        <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy" InputGestureText="Ctrl+C" />
        <MenuItem Header="Paste" Command="Paste" InputGestureText="Ctrl+V" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="_View">
        <MenuItem x:Name="miShowStatusBar" Header="Show Status Bar" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Click="miShowStatusBar_Click"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="miShowFullPath" Header="Show Full Path" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Click="miShowFullPath_Click"/>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="_Help">
        <MenuItem Header="_About"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

The menu is not referenced any where in the code behind so I can't figure out what might be causing this odd menu placement.

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my side, have you any style applied to your menu ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the source of the OP's problem is in the search box under the `MenuBar`. It may come from the Margin or Width settings of the search box.

I faced the same problem and found the sources. Here is the boilerplate code to reproduce the same error. The problem is a combination of 5 parts, as shown in the following XAML. Remove any one of them will solve the OP's issue.

You need to bind the XAML View to a ViewModel with public property `Films`. If the `Films` collection has any element in it, it will also cause the issue (Part 5).

```
    <Grid x:Name="MainContent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid >
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Film">
                <MenuItem Header="New"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid>
            <!--Part 1: Remove HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"-->
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <!--Part 2: Remove ItemsSource="{Binding Films}"-->
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Films}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <!--Part 3: Remove the setter tag-->
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button>
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <!--Part 4: Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=ActualWidth}-->
                                        <ContentPresenter Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with WPF.  It's a possible corruption of the Handedness setting or driver issues if you have a touch screen monitor, tablet PC or have a tablet attached with a bad driver (such as a Wacom drawing tablet).

Type this into the **Run** dialog: `shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}`.
Once **Tablet PC Settings** come up, go to the **Other** tab and in the **Handedness** section, check the **Left Handed** option.

Comment: Trying this has no effect.  Additionally, if this was the problem it would likely still be attached to the menu bar.  In this case it is not attached to the application at all but instead in the same place all the time regardless of where the application is.  Specifically the top left of the first monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I bet that this has something to do with the Xaml-Designer of your Visual Studio instance. I encounter similar strange things because of leaving the Xaml-Designer open while debugging.

Try to kill the `XDesProc.exe` process and check if the problem still occurs.